# Fast matrix multiplication with matrix elements computed on-the-fly (without forming the matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, blas, dense-matrix

Is there any library or routine for high-performance matrix-matrix product, where the matrix elements are computed on-the-fly using a given function of $i$ and $j$?

More specifically, in the problem I am currently facing, I have to compute a matrix-matrix product

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{b}
$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a symmetric matrix $N \times N$,  $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are $N\times 3$.

Using LAPACK or BLAS routines requires the formation of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. The matrix elements, however, are a function that depends only on the matrix indices $i,j$.

Comment: how large might be $N$? is $\mathbf{A}$ (even though its elements depend only on $i,j$) sparse?

Comment: How big is your $N$?  Is $A$ sparse or dense?  How large a submatrix of $A$ can you work with at one time in main memory? How simple is the function that computes the entry of $A$ for a given $i$ and $j$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers The matrix is dense. N will be at the order of 1,000 to 5,000. I do not form the matrix $\mathbf{A}$; all elements are computed on-the-fly; thus I am not restricted to the size of the submatrix that can fit in main memory. The function is $\mathbf{A}(i,j) = 1/(1+\|x_i - x_j\|^2)$ where $x$ is a known vector (size $N\times 1$). This is not the only function, but an example of a function I am currently using.

Comment: You haven't given any context to explain why it is necessary to avoid forming the matrix $A$?  Your matrix is quite small and could easily fit into memory.  Since $A_{i,j}$ is quite expensive to compute it will be fastest to just form $A$ and use optimized BLAS routines to do the multiplication.

Comment: Looks like a job for the fast multipole method?

Answer (score 3):

If the matrix is small enough to fit into memory, then there is of course no cost associated with actually forming the elements: You will have to compute the elements at least once anyway to perform the matrix-vector product, so you might as well store the values you computed in memory and then run an optimized matrix-vector product function over it.

But there are of course cases where you genuinely can't or don't want to compute and store the matrix entries. An example is if $A=BC$ where $B$ and $C$ are other matrices and where it is cheaper to compute $y=Ab$ via $B(Cb)$ than $(BC)b$. Other cases are where $A$ does not fit into memory.

In these cases, you need a library that allows you to implement a matrix via its *action*, i.e., its matrix-vector product. One example is PETSc where you can create a `MatShell` object -- a matrix for which you need to provide a pointer to a function that can perform matrix-vector products. Most other linear algebra libraries have similar functionality -- I'm pretty sure Trilinos can do this, and deal.II (disclaimer: that's a project I'm associated with) does this all over the place by creating classes that provide a matrix-vector multiplication member function.